# How to reach OLAP Cubes by msmdpump.dll on 64 bit Server?

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, olap, filemaker

I have a analysis server database that runs Windows Server 2008 64 bits. And users reach cubes by msmdpump.dll. There is any problem before used FileMaker on same server. I could not analysis server database. I searched some documents that say I must change the application pool to 32 bit enabled. I changed OLAP web.config and added ISAPI filter. Also I read that I should use 32 bit msmdpump.dll but I run IIS 64 bit and how could you find 32 bit dll. Now I can  not reached in any way. Could you help me what steps need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

To install and configure OLAP Pump for IIS x64 connecting to an SSAS x64 instance, you use the msmdpump.dll of your x64 SSAS installation dir. To access an SSAS x86 instance, you use the msmdpump.dll of your x86 SSAS installation dir. The second variant requires you to enable 32 bit on your application pool.

A very nice guide of how to set up SSAS access via IIS can be found here:

[Microsoft - Configure HTTP Access to SSAS via IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx)

Many thanks and best regards